# MapView stopped showing the map (signed application)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

My application signed with MapView, was working perfectly, however this week the Google map stopped working (in debug mode everything runs fine), but whenever I generate a signed application the map dont display Maps tiles (no error occurs, nothing is shown in logcat). This is being caused by the fact that the API 1 is obsolete?

Comment: Are you using correct apiKey on the mapView? I'm assuming you used debug apiKey since you say debug mode everything runs fine, did you changed to the apiKey of signature keystore?

Comment: Yes I am using the correct, everything was working properly until this week.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the new Google Map V2 anf key generation Process 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: It is not possible to generate key for API 1.